# Why does roslyn wrap objects in structures when put in arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, roslyn

While reading through the source code of [Roslyn on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), I noticed the much used [`ObjectPool<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Core/SharedCollections/ObjectPool%601.cs) class. It is used to reduce memory overhead.

Internally it uses [an array](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Core/SharedCollections/ObjectPool%601.cs#L57) to store the pooled objects.
What I don't understand is why it uses a private struct called `Element` containing a single field of type `T` as array element, instead of just using `T`.

Is this out of concern for performance? Memory overhead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It may be for performance reasons.  See [this article by Jon Skeet](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/06/22/array-covariance-not-just-ugly-but-slow-too/).

To summarize, value type arrays are invariant in C#, which means the runtime can avoid doing a compatibility check when storing items in the array.  In the article, Mr. Skeet uses a wrapper structure similar to the one you described and shows an improvement in write performance to the array.

Comment: Holy.....i didn't expect this, should be possible to declare the arrays itself as invariant. Would be much nicer than do this workaround. Now i need to change some stuff in my visualization engine. :-/

Comment: Damn... I didn't know this. I'm definitely gonna check some code tomorrow :-\

Comment: I have posted a [feature proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4211) on the [Roslyn project](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). It's meant to make using invariant arrays a little bit easier.